# Shadows on alpha channel PNG's and eevee

Tags: transparency, shadows, eevee-render-engine

I am playing with the eevee render, and I am struggling on how to render projected shadows from objects textured with alpha channel.

Here is a reference render on cycles on what I want to achieve.

[image]

And here is my result on Eevee

[image]

My texture is pretty simple.
[image]

And I have turned on the shadow checkboxes on both the light panel

[image]

And my render panel

[image]

I am using the 2.80 A build from 2018-11-23

**Can this type of shadows be rendered at all?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to change some of the material's options :

[image: demo pic]

It works for me with *Blend mode* to *alpha blend*, and *transparent shadow* to *clip*.

Answer (score 3):

The current version of blender has slightly different ui to do this now, so I decided to add my answer as an update.  Without changing any settings and using a basic noise texture for transparency in a cube, I notice that I get no transparency even though the nodes are completely correct.  Here's the result:

[image: without settings changed]

The fix is easy.  select the material in the properties tab, scroll down until you reach the settings in the below picture.

[image]

click the **blend mode** dropbox, and select **alpha clip**

[image]

now the alpha works as shown, but the shadows still aren't working.

[image]

go back to the settings, select the **shadow mode** drop box, and turn *it* to **alpha clip**.

[image]

This fixes the alpha! anyway, just thought I would update.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update. It is always wellcome.

Comment: no problem, @Rafael , thanks for the support.  =)